# Stop firebase file uploading task in android?

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

Here i tried to upload file from the recyclerview using Asynctask.
The uploading work set in doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) method.
What had i did

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setName(params[0].message_push_id);// here i set the background therad name

            filepath.putFile(sendingImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(
                                UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                        {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                            Intent intent=new Intent("data_changed");
                        intent.putExtra("UploadProgress",(int)progress);
                        intent.putExtra("UploadPosition",newPosition);
                        intent.putExtra("UploadPushId",message_push_id);
                        Log.i("atsender",String.valueOf((int)progress)+":"+String.valueOf(newPosition)+":"+message_push_id);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MessageActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

This progress i received in adapter class through the `LocalBroadcastManager` and i tried to stop this process from holderview like below code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Thread thread=getThreadByName(pushId);
                    if (pushId==null)
                    {
                        Log.i("thread_status", "there no active thread named of "pushId");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         thread.interrupt();
                    }
                }
            });
```

by using `thread.interrupt();` uploading progress is not stop it still return the uploading progress.
SO How to stop uploading task which is running in recyclerview or listview

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Storage SDK already performs all network and disk I/O on a separate thread, so there's no need for you to wrap this in an `AsyncTask` yourself.

You can cancel Firebase's upload by calling `cancel()` on the upload task. See the Firebase documentation on [monitoring uploads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#manage_uploads). Based on that:

```
UploadTask task = filepath.putFile(sendingImageURI);
task.addOnCompleteListener(...
);

task.cancel();
```

Comment: I use asynctask beacuse of multi threading.Ok,..so how can i find this UploadTask while it is running from activity .No global variable defined

Comment: This is sample of downloader, concept is same but in my case this uploader(not a downloader)....https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f9832d6f603677aa23d4eba0c029f41d160580c8/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f423764477655652e706e67

Comment: In this image pause/resume button and i have cancel button to intrupt uploading task

Comment: I showed exactly how to do that and why you don't need your own `AsyncTask`. I'm not sure how to help further.